# javascript "classes" vs an array tracker

Tags: javascript

I thought that I had asked this before but I guess not. And I know JS doesn't really have "classes" but y'all know what I mean.

I'm wondering if there are any obvious issues with one method over the other.

I'll explain by example:

**Method 1** -- using an array to track each "instance"

```
var method1 = (function()
{
    // store each "instance"
    var tracker = [];

    return {
        // main function
        "init" : function(data)
        {
            // store the instance and return its index
            return tracker.push(data) - 1;
        },
        // gets passed the index of the item
        "doSomething" : function(index)
        {
            // get the item and then do something to item
            var data = tracker[index];

            alert(data);
        }
    };
})();

var i1 = method1.init("hi");
var i2 = method1.init("bye");

method1.doSomething(i1); // alerts "hi"
method1.doSomething(i2); // alertrs "bye"
```

**Method 2** -- "classes"

```
var method2 = (function()
{
    var init = function(data)
    {
        var myData = data;

        this.getData = function()
        {
            return myData;
        }
    };

    init.prototype.doSomething = function()
    {
        alert(this.getData());
    }


    return init;
})();

var i1 = new method2("hi");
var i2 = new method2("bye");

i1.doSomething(); // alerts "hi"
i2.doSomething(); // alerts "bye"
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do here? And what's wrong with ES 6 classes with babel transpilation for old browser? Roll-your-own is not a good MO...

Comment: I am stuck, for now, writing code that works in IE 11 stuck in IE 7 compatibility mode.

Comment: My apologies then...and my condolences.

Comment: Thanks. I've been fighting my IT team but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the obvious issue with method 1 is that the tracker data is never garbage collected (unless the whole `method1` module is deleted at some point).

So don't do that, use an instance-based approach like method 2. As soon as you do `i1 = null`, the string `"hi"` can be released.

Comment: It would be GCd at browser close, right? The library I'm writing is intended to be available the entire life of the browsing.

Comment: Yes, of course it's collected when the program ends (which can take months for a browser!), but until then it's a memory leak. And yes, while you want the library to be available the whole time, you don't want *all instances* to be available the whole time.

Comment: That sir/ma'am, is a really good point. Thank you! Time to re-write my library.